# Update nested attributes in a JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I want to change 'hello' to 'hey' programmatically, the solution should work with any number of nested elements (I just use 2 levels to keep it simple).

```
var data = {level1: {level2 : 'hello' }};
```

I have access to the 'data' variable, the path ('level1/level2') and the new value ('hey').

I tried to do:

```
var parents = 'level1/level2'.split('/');
var target = data;
for(var i=0; i<parents.length; i++){
   target = data[parents[i]];
}
target = 'hey';
```

The idea was to travel to the root

```
target = data
```

then 1 level deep

```
target = data['level1']
```

...keep going

```
target = data['level1']['level2'] //data['level1'] === target
```

and modify the contents

```
target = 'hey'
```

But it looks like a lose the reference to the original object (data) when I do (target = target['level2']).

I guess I can build a string with the path and then evaluate it:

```
eval("data['level1']['level2']='hey');
```

Is there a better solution that dosen't involve eval()?

Comment: "...lose the reference to the original object" then don't...keep a variable pointing to the original data object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues. First is that you keep using `data` inside the loop, which means you're trying to access the top level keys instead of the inner keys. Change `target = data[parents[i]];` to

```
target = target[parents[i]];
```

The second is that when you change the variable `target`, you're not changing the `data` variable but `target` instead. If you drop out of the loop one iteration earlier you can update the object which is stored as a reference:

```
for(var i=0; i<parents.length-1; i++){
   target = target[parents[i]];
}
target[parents[i]] = 'hey';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Lherp/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var data = {level1: {level2 : 'hello' }};
var parents = 'level1/level2'.split('/');
var target = data;
for(var i=0; i < parents.length - 1; i++){
   target = target[parents[i]];
}
target[parents[i]] = 'hey';
```

Or am I missing something?

edit: I was missing something (sorry, should have tested it first..)

Comment: That's what I posted, no? console.log(data.level1.level2) outputs 'hello' instead of 'hey'.

Comment: Changing the `target` variable doesn't update the `data` object.