# shallow copy not updating in nested JSON object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have an nested JSON object like this:

```
var jsonObj = 
{ "level1" : 
      { "status" : true,
        "level2" : {} // and it has the same format and can go to level3, 4, etc
       }
}
```

What I want to do is simple, I want to get to Level2, and add a new Level3 object to it.
Basically I want to do the following code below, but since the levels are dynamic, I need a function that traverse my object.

`obj.Level1.Level2.Level3 = { 'status' : true}`

Here's my snippet of code:

```
function updateStatusForLevel(nestedObj, categoryHierarchy){
        // categoryHierarchy that is passed = ['Level1', 'Level2', 'Level3']; 
        var obj = nestedObj;

        angular.forEach(categoryHierarchy, function(value, key){
            obj = obj[value];


            if (key === categoryHierarchy.length - 1 && angular.isUndefined(obj)){
                 obj[value] = {}; // I want to add 'Level3' = {}
            }
        });
        obj.status = 'true'; // and finally, update the status 
        console.info("my original obj is " + JSON.stringify(nestedObj));
    }
```

However seems like I'm missing something. If I do this, my original nestedObj is still the same as what I'm passing in (it's not updated, only the `obj` object is updated. I believe this should be a really simple code that traverse a nested JSON object. Why is the shallow copy not updating the original object?

Comment: can you provide a plunkr link ?

Comment: obj[value].status = 'true'; u r accessing value outside the foreach.

Comment: what is objHierarchy in foreach?

Comment: @manivannan sorry I copied the code and changed some variables name to be simple, but i changed some incorrectly. code is updated

Comment: can't u provide plunker? i think obj is undefined. because u r assigning obj[value] aftet obj was assigned.  obj = obj[value]; put this line after if condition in foreach\.

Comment: @manivannan I just found out my question is similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033318/update-nested-attributes-in-a-javascript-object?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
function updateStatusForLevel(nestedObj, categoryHierarchy){
        // categoryHierarchy that is passed = ['Level1', 'Level2', 'Level3']; 
        if(categoryHierarchy.length) {
             var shifted = categoryHierarchy.shift();
             nestedObj[shifted] = {status: true};
             return updateStatusForLevel(starter[shifted], categoryHierarchy);
       } else {
             return nestedObj;
       }
}
```

Then calling `updateStatusForLevel(nestedObj, ['level1', 'level2', 'level3'])` will modify `nestedObj` as

```
level1: Object
    level2: Object
        level3: Object
            status: true
        status: true
    status: true
```

*note, this answer is not clever, so better have plnkr or something for better asnwer, but for now, try this in browser dev console*

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want to add a value from a certain path of nested objects, then how about creating a generic function that can do this, instead of creating a custom one. I have created a factory named `helper`, which can be a collection of helper functions that you may want to add later on.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fm3cy3W2G7pMmf5foBON?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .factory('helper', function() {

    var helper = {};

    helper.set = function(object, path, value) {

      // save reference of an object
      var reference = object,
          // last key n the path
          lastKey;

      path = angular.isArray(path)? path: // set as an array if it is an array
          angular.isString(path)? path.split('.'): // split the path as an array if it is a string
          false; // set to false and do nothing if neither of the conditions above satisfies

      // check if path is truthy
      if(path) {

        // get the last key of the path
        lastKey = path.pop();

        // reduce the references until all the remaining keys
        reference = path.reduce(function(reference, key) {

          // check if the current object reference is undefined
          if(angular.isUndefined(reference[key])) {
            // set current object reference as an object if it is undefined
            reference[key] = {};
          }

          // return the current object reference for the next iteration
          return reference[key];

        }, reference); 

        // set the last object reference for the value
        reference[lastKey] = value;

      }

      return object;

    };

    return helper;

  })

  .run(function(helper) {

    var object1 = {},
        object2 = {},
        object3 = {},

        object4 = { 
          "level1" : { 
            "status" : true,
            "level2" : {}
          }
        };

    helper.set(object1, 'z.k.v.q', { status: false });
    // object1 = { z: { k: { v: { q: { status: false } } } } }
    console.log(object1);

    helper.set(object2, 'a.e.i.o.u', { status: true });
    // object2 = { a: { e: { i: { o: { u: { status: true } } } } } }
    console.log(object2);

    helper.set(object3, ['hello', 'world'], { status: undefined });
    // object3 = { hello: { world: { status: undefined } } }
    console.log(object3);

    helper.set(object4, 'level1.level2.level3', { status: true });
    // object4 = { status: true, level1: { level2: { level3: { status: true } } } }
    console.log(object4);

  });
```

Alternatively, you can use [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/) for this, and you'd be able to do more object, array and collection manipulation. The `lodash` function you should be looking for would be [`_.set()`](https://lodash.com/docs#set)

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/387tzAfbdPDhTZCOrWmP?p=preview)**

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
  .service('_', function($window) {
    // you can add mixins here
    // read more about lodash if you
    // want to customize data manipulation
    return $window._;
  })

  .run(function(_) {

    var object1 = {},
        object2 = {},
        object3 = {},

        object4 = { 
          "level1" : { 
            "status" : true,
            "level2" : {}
          }
        };

    _.set(object1, 'z.k.v.q', { status: false });
    // object1 = { z: { k: { v: { q: { status: false } } } } }
    console.log(object1);

    _.set(object2, 'a.e.i.o.u', { status: true });
    // object2 = { a: { e: { i: { o: { u: { status: true } } } } } }
    console.log(object2);

    _.set(object3, ['hello', 'world'], { status: undefined });
    // object3 = { hello: { world: { status: undefined } } }
    console.log(object3);

    _.set(object4, 'level1.level2.level3', { status: true });
    // object4 = { status: true, level1: { level2: { level3: { status: true } } } }
    console.log(object4);

  });
```